Why there not occur a saddle point in Lagrange Min/Max when the point is regular?
We stated the Lagrange Theorem as follows:
Let $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n,~ h\in C^1(U, \mathbb{R})$ be a function and $\varphi \in C^1(U, \mathbb{R}^k)$ the additional conditions. Let $a$ be a Maximum with respect to $\varphi$ that is  $h(a)-h(x)$ does not change the sign in $V \cap \{\varphi = 0\}$ for a neighbourhood $V$ of $a$.
If $D\varphi (a)$ is surjective, then there exists a $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^k$ s.t. $$Dh(a) + \lambda D\varphi(a) = 0$$
What we do in practise is to solve $Dh(x) + \lambda D\varphi(x) = 0$ for an $a$ and show that $D\varphi$ is surjectiv for all $x\in U \cap \{\varphi=0\}$. Why can we say that $a$ is a local extremum, couldn't it be that the so found $a$ is a saddle point of the function on $\varphi=0$? If it is possible that there is a saddle point, can you give an Example?

Yes, it is possible that a stationary point of the Lagrangian is a saddle point. Being a stationary point of the Lagrangian is only a necessary condition.
id the admissible region is compact, you can easily identify the global minimum and maximum just by computing the value of $f$ of the stationary points. In general, you need to use higher order criteria, lookup for instance for the bordered Hessian criteria.
